# How can a "background" thread submit tasks to TKInter's GUI thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, networking

Okay long-story-short, I am making program which has to deal with Tkinter GUI and Networking. So I made the client-server connectivity on the main thread and a additional thread will run parallel to the main thread which will execute all the GUI Tkinter based work. Now I have reached a Deadlock situation where I need a call a function in the GUI thread(2nd thread) from the main thread. I am open to suggestions to do something like that or achieve something like what I described above.

Thanks for your answers in advance! Cheers!

Comment: I'd make one thread for the GUI that just reads messages from a message queue and have worker threads to do anything time consuming. Whenever a worker thread is done and it's time to present something in the GUI, put a message in the message queue

Comment: You cannot, in general, have one thread _force_ any other thread to do anything. But, most GUI frameworks provide a queue where other threads can submit tasks to be performed by the GUI thread. I don't know TKInter. I don't know if it has such a queue, but I'm changing the title of your question so that maybe it will attract more attention.

Comment: Solomon I respect your modification you did to my question but I think I failed to express my question my question properly. The "background" thread is actually the main thread on which the program's core runs and from it diverges the gui thread to handle all the gui stuff. I don't know about the queue thing in tkinter framework and look it up. Again thanks for answering

Comment: I don't know that "bacckground" has any specific technical meaning. I was thinking in this case that the GUI thread is "foreground" because it is in control of what the user sees on the screen, and every other thread is a "background" thread because they work behind the scenes, so to speak. Also, For whatever it's worth, I have heard _some_ GUI developers (not me though!) use the phrase "main thread" to mean the GUI thread even in programs where the GUI thread is not the thread that started the program.